# Autofill checkbox using string query in url but specifying a fieldset

Tags: string, url, checkbox, fieldset

I'm trying to get filtered data from a webform more quickly. Basically I want to use URL input to specify a date and to precheck a checkbox. I'm getting stuck with how to specify the check box as I'm not sure what the value should be.

```html
<form action="/xxx/yyy" class="form-inline d-flex justify-content-end" method="get">      <div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="from" value="" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="datetimepicker7" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#datetimepicker7" autocomplete="false">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>

####snip and skip to the part of the form I wish to pre-check####

<fieldset id="departureGatewayFilters">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="AMS" id="departureGatewayCheck_AMS">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="departureGatewayCheck_AMS">
                AMS
              </label>
            </div>
```

So far I'm using URL string: /xxx/yyy?from=2020-03-05 - what would I need next to pre-check the checkbox as well?

Thanks in advance!

Clare

Answer (score 1):

Getting your checkbox checked and also getting value of the checkbox just through URL string is little bit troublesome. But you can try this :

You can assign unique name to the checkbox.

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" id="departureGatewayCheck_AMS">
```

And then what you can do is pass the value of checkbox through URL string. For example :

`/xxx/yyy?from=2020-03-05&checkbox_1=test`.

Now, using javascript you can parse URL strings and get your search params, compare it and get your checkbox checked.

```
<script lang="javascript">
    var url_string = window.location.href ; //gets current URL
    var url = new URL(url_string); // instantiate string as URL object
    var c = url.searchParams.get("checkbox_1"); //get the params

    if(c == "test") {
        document.getElementById("departureGatewayCheck_AMS").checked = true; //checks your checkbox
    }
</script>
```

Hope it helps ! Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the checkbox departureGatewayCheck_AMS checked by default, it is sufficient to edit its code like this:

```html
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="AMS" name="departureGatewayCheck_AMS" id="departureGatewayCheck_AMS" checked> AMS
```

If the checkbox is selected, since its "value" attribute is "AMS",your url (if you submit the form via GET) would be something like:

> /xxx/yyy?from=2020-03-05&departureGatewayCheck_AMS=AMS

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is add a (checked="true") argument to your input tag your code should look like this then:

```
<div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" checked="true" type="checkbox" value="AMS" id="departureGatewayCheck_AMS">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="departureGatewayCheck_AMS">
                AMS
          </label>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Complete solution for your requirement:-**

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-yMjaV542P+q1RnH6XByCPDfUFhmOafWbeLPmqKh11zo=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
```

```
<div class="container">
 <form class="form-inline d-flex justify-content-end" method="get">      <div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-2">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="from" value="" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="datetimepicker7" autocomplete="false">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> 
</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<fieldset id="departureGatewayFilters">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" name="checkname" type="checkbox" value="AMS" id="departureGatewayCheck_AMS">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="departureGatewayCheck_AMS">
            AMS
          </label>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
 </div>
 </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
       var url_string = "https://www.example.com/page?from=2020-12-12&checkname=1";//window.location.href ; //gets current URL
       var url = new URL(url_string); // instantiate string as URL object
       var date=url.searchParams.get("from");
    var check = url.searchParams.get("checkname"); //get the params
alert(date);
alert(check);
if(check) {
    $( "#departureGatewayCheck_AMS" ).prop( "checked", true );
}
            $('.datetimepicker-input').datetimepicker({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                defaultDate: date,
            });
        });
    </script>
```